# Splitting a String then adding the two Strings together

Tags: java

Hi I am wondering how to take a String called s, splitting it into two separate Strings, turning the Strings into ints, then adding the two ints together.

```
public String add() throws IOException {

    int answer;

    String s = input;

    String[] strings = s.split(" + ");
    String string1 = strings[0].trim();
    String string2 = strings[1].trim();

    int x = Integer.parseInt(string1);
    int y = Integer.parseInt(string2);

    answer = x + y;
    System.out.println(answer);
    return "" + answer;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem here?

Comment: To read from the command line, use :
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  input = in.nextLine()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this pattern

```
String[] strings = s.split("\\+");
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the `input` variable as function argument

```
public String add(String input) throws IOException {
```

then instead of String s = input`;

use

```
String[] strings = input.split(" + ");
```

then call

```
add("3 + 2");
```